# How to use static methods of JavaCV in Android using static OpenCV

Tags: android, opencv, javacv

I need OpenCV to be static to avoid installing the OpenCV Manager in the phone.
The OpenCV compiles OK, ive included all the .so needed under /lib in the android proyect. I also included al the jars needed for JavaCV, but it displays this message:
`Could not find method org.bytedeco.javacpp.opencv_highgui.cvLoadImage`
 The strange thing is that IplImage works fine, but when trying to do cvLoadImage:

> VFY: unable to resolve static method 9062: Lorg/bytedeco/javacpp/opencv_highgui;.cvLoadImage (Ljava/lang/String;)Lorg/bytedeco/javacpp/opencv_core$IplImage;

Answer (score 1):

Not sure but probably you included only opencv_core lib while opencv_highgui left missing. That`s why only IplImage is visible.

Comment: +1. It sounds like you have only included one library and not all the libraries that are used within your code.

Comment: Ive included import static org.bytedeco.javacpp.opencv_core.*;
import static org.bytedeco.javacpp.opencv_highgui.*; OpenCV is the latest (2.4.9) and javacv is 0.8

Comment: Open your APK and check for *.so files. Each module should have its own *.so file.

Comment: The .so i have are: libopencv_info.so lobopencv_java.so and linnative_camera_r*.*.*.so, but these ones are from opencv, isnt this a javacv trouble?

Comment: Yes, it looks like. I would start with finding the proper version of javacv or compile it by yourself.

Comment: Ive tried extracting all the so files from opencv-android-arm.jar (for example highui.so) but im still having the same results